# Web Browser Kiosk Temporary Internet Files

Tags: security, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

For a PC that is set up as a kiosk always running a web browser, are there settings available in the major web browsers to delete the temporary internet files periodically?  I know Firefox has settings to clear them upon closing the browser but this browser would always be up and running.

Answer (score 1):

There's an article here that explains how to force major browsers to start in private mode.

http://www.guidingtech.com/3246/start-internet-explorer-firefox-chrome-in-private-browsing-mode/

You could write a program to periodically delete temporary files when a browser isnt running.